# Get user info information from Google Plus API with PHP

Tags: php, json, get

When you're visiting this page:

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z12gtjhq3qn2xxl2o224exwiqruvtda0i?key=AIzaSyAwnz3yjIcvsosfbudkzl9oogGrT21m6Ns

...I guess what is called an object, appears with a lot of information. But when I try to do a simple GET call and then print it, like so:

```
$tweets = $_GET['https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z12gtjhq3qn2xxl2o224exwiqruvtda0i?key=AIzaSyAwnz3yjIcvsosfbudkzl9oogGrT21m6Ns'];
print_r($tweets);
```

...It returns nothing... Why is that?

Comment: `$_GET['']` is for query parameters, not to make a GET request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$_GET` super global is populated with the query string of the current request, it's not used to *get* stuff from the interwebs.

You're looking for [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents):

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z12gtjhq3qn2xxl2o224exwiqruvtda0i?key=AIzaSyAwnz3yjIcvsosfbudkzl9oogGrT21m6Ns';
$tweets = file_get_contents($url);
print_r($tweets);
```

If that contains a JSON encoded response you need to additionally use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to use `$_GET`?
Check PHP documentation, you must have made a mistake, or you're using it the wrong way.